# Script to upload several .xyz files into QGIS

Tags: pyqgis

The following script has the purpose to upload all .xyz files into QGIS that are within the folder xyz_data. That's the script:

```
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer, QgsProject
import glob, os

dir = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/xyz_data"

os.chdir(dir)

for file in glob.glob("*.xyz"):
    uri = "file://" + dir + file + "?delimiter=%s&xField=%s&yField=%s" % (" ", "field_1", "field_2")
    name = file.replace('.xyz', '')
    lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, name, "delimitedtext")
    QgsProject().instance().addMapLayer(lyr)
```

When I run the command in the python console the names of the files appear in the QGIS layerlist but there is no data and I get an attention sign next to the layer. There is no attribute table I could open nor can I zoom to the layer

[image]

Hovering over the attention sign gives me the following error message:

> **No available Layer!** Layer data source was not found.

Apparently it has something to do with the uri. However, I don't see any errors in the code. 
The directory is correct, I went to the folder and copy & pasted the url.

Perhaps there is something wrong with writing `+ file +`?

Perhaps I don't get the whole filename as a string?

The delimiter is correct as well. 
The xField and yField names are correct as well I think. The file itself already starts with the x-coordinate and doesn't have a line called xField, however when I upload each file manually, QGIS represents the columns as "field_1" and so on.

Does anyone see the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to append a forward slash in your dir so that it looks like:

```
dir = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/xyz_data/"
```

---

And as you figured out, you need three forward slashes when defining the file url:

```
"file:///..."
```